# Static code analyzer for Python catching module privacy hints

Tags: python, debugging, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

Say I have a module `test.py`:

```python
def foo():
   print "foo"

def bar():
   print "bar"

def _baz():
   print "_baz"

__all__ = ['foo']
```

and a `main.py`:

```python
from test import foo, bar, _baz

foo()
bar()   # breaks module privacy
_baz()  # breaks module privacy
```

Is there any (static) code analyzer tool for Python that will catch the imports breaking the privacy (`bar`, `_baz`) hinted by `__all__`?

I have tested Pylint, but it does not catch either.

Another clarification: I am not talking about situation where `__all__` would be dynamically modified/filled and/or where importing code is dynamic. Just statically analyzable code situations.

Comment: Python doesn't *have* privacy. `__all__` is a hint to limit what is imported by `from module import *` and what `help()` reports. *That is the limit* of it's usefulness.

Comment: Well, thats obvious, but not my question.

Comment: As such, there are no existing tools that will flag this. You'd also have to flag `import test; test._baz`, etc.

Comment: Sure, those imports also "violate" the `__all__` hint. It's just an example.

Comment: What I mean is: because `__all__`'s intention has nothing to do with privacy (it is not a limit on what is exported, it is a tool to delimit *wildcard importing*) no tool in the Python ecosystem exists that takes that interpretation and tracks usage of names that are not listed in `__all__`.

Comment: Well, really, I do know all what you say in your first sentance (`__all__` being there to limit effect of `from X import *` etc), but the 2nd sentance is what I am after: so you say there definitely is no tool that does static analysis as said? Thats surprising and unfortunate. Post it as an answer and I accept.

Comment: I understand you concern about privacy violation, but thats normally a decision of the user of the module/class and not the module/class implementor. You only gives warnings like "you should not need/use this" but you should not enforce that. Thats just a convention. Also, im curious, why not make `bar` use the privacy convention and turn it into a `_bar`?

Comment: Again: I understand there is no _run-time_ support in Python to support privacy enforcement. I am asking about _static code analysis_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `__all__`'s intention has nothing to do with privacy (it is not a limit on what is exported, it is a tool to delimit *wildcard importing*) no tool in the Python ecosystem exists that takes that interpretation and tracks usage of names that are not listed in `__all__`.

In other words; `__all__` was never intended as a means to bless only parts of the exported names as public, just as `_name` leading underscores are just private by convention and not enforced.

Comment: I guess I need to write a static code analyzer capable of checking `_name` == private convention myself? Well;)

Comment: Indeed; study the source code of existing analyzers (pyflakes, etc.) to see how they do it. AST analysis isn't that hard.